# How to configure multilanguage site setup in contao?

Tags: multilingual, contao

I'm new in contao. can any one tell how to configure multilanguage site setup in contao ?

Answer (score 4):

By default, multiple languages in Contao are handled by using multiple *Website roots*. Edit the properties of a website root and look under *DNS settings »* **Language**. For your primary/fallback language you should also enable the option **Language fallback** to the right.

When creating a second language, you create a new *Website root* and in the aforementioned settings you insert the correct IETF language tag. Within this website root you can build the website independently in the new language. You could also copy an existing website root, including its whole site structure and articles.

If you are using different domains for each language, you have to set the respective domain under **Domain name**. If not, you should probably enable the option **Add the language to the URL** within *System » Settings » Front end configuration*.

If you want to implement a language switcher in the frontend, you can use the [[changelanguage](https://contao.org/en/extension-list/view/changelanguage.en.html)] extension.